# Convert double to integer mantissa and exponents

Tags: c++, floating-point, asn.1

I am trying extract the mantissa and exponent part from the double.
For the test data '0.15625', expected mantissa and exponent are '5' and '-5' respectively (5*2^-5).

```
double value = 0.15625; 
double mantissa  = frexp(value, &exp);
```

`Result: mantissa = 0.625 and exp = -2`.

Here the mantissa returned is a fraction. For my use case (ASN.1 encoding), mantissa should be integer. I understand by right-shifting the mantissa and adjusting the exponent, I can convert binary fraction to the integer. In the eg, `0.625 base 10` is `0.101 base 2`, so `3` bytes to be shifted to get the integer. But I am finding it difficult to find a generic algorithm.

So my question is, how do I calculate the number bits to be shifted to convert a decimal fraction to a binary integer?

Comment: I guess `frexp` is not what you need, because it returns a *normalized* value - in the range `[0.5, 1)` (or the corresponding negative range). Can you explain what you actually need the two integer values for? Maybe a simple bit-extraction would be better suited?

Comment: @Adrian my final aim is to get it encoded in the ASN.1 REAL format. I would like to get an algorithm to convert the fraction binary to integer binary.

Comment: Keep multiplying `mantissa` by `2` and subtracting `1` from `exp` until `mantissa` has a value equal to an integral value (or, since this is floating point, apply a tolerance to that check  i.e. until the absolute value of the difference between `mantissa` and an integral value is less than your chosen tolerance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <cmath>        //  For frexp.
#include <iomanip>      //  For fixed and setprecision.
#include <iostream>     //  For cout.
#include <limits>       //  For properties of floating-point format.


int main(void)
{
    double value = 0.15625;

    //  Separate value into significand in [.5, 1) and exponent.
    int exponent;
    double significand = std::frexp(value, &exponent);

    //  Scale significand by number of digits in it, to produce an integer.
    significand = scalb(significand, std::numeric_limits<double>::digits);

    //  Adjust exponent to compensate for scaling.
    exponent -= std::numeric_limits<double>::digits;

    //  Set stream to print significand in full.
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0);

    //  Output triple with significand, base, and exponent.
    std::cout << "(" << significand << ", "
        << std::numeric_limits<double>::radix << ", " << exponent << ")\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
(5629499534213120, 2, -55)
```

(If the value is zero, you might wish to force the exponent to zero, for aesthetic reasons. Mathematically, any exponent would be correct.)

Comment: And if the mantissa is even you could divide it by two and adjust the exponent to get a smaller representation.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: This code and the ASN.1 specification do not assume the floating-point radix is two.

Comment: Sorry, should have said if `mantissa % base == 0` then you can divide by `base`.